# Pagination in Classic ASP with VB Script

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, pagination

I am using ASP/VB Script in my project but, i don't have much idea of Pagination in Classic ASP. I have designed a datagrid format using tables and looping. That table is filled by accessing database. As we have a huge amount of data to display, we need pagination.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you just do a search on the title of your post you will find many examples and source code to work from.

Answer (score 2):

The pagination problem is not inherently to ASP classic or VBScript. You need first to define which strategy to follow:

### In the client:

1. Ajax style pagination (You can use a jQuery plugin like [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid))
2. Linked pagination: Your page have links to page 1, page 2, etc.
3. Infite scrolling: This is a modern way to do pagination, with more results added to the page via ajax

### In the server

1. Full DB results retrieve and return only the page asked. This is sometimes necessary.
2. Full DB retrieve but caching the result so subsequent page request come from the cache, not the DB
3. Ask the DB only the page asked (Different techniques depending on the DB engine)

Answer (score 1):

There is a issue you need to be aware of... the built-in ASP record set will allow pagiing, however is not very efficient. The entire result set gets returned to the browser and then it locates the appropriate page and displays that data.

Think of it like this... your result set is a 4 shelf book case. When you ask for page one  all 4 shelves of books get returned. The the display code says "Okay now only show page 1". If you then ask for page two... All four shelves of books gets returned and then the display code says "Okay give me page 4".

So, you should look for a paging solution that takes place on the server, inside the database. This way if you ask for page 15 of a 50 page result, the database will only return one shelf of books.

This [google query](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1348&bih=839&q=stored%20procedure%20paging&oq=stored%20procedure%20pa&aq=6&aqi=g10&aql=&gs_sm=c&gs_upl=5297l23297l0l27906l58l58l19l16l23l0l219l3112l6.15.2l23l0) should put you on the right track.

#### Edit: How SQL Paging Works

1. You must us a stored procedure
2. One of the input parameters is the page to view
3. The stored procedure filters the results on the server

Here is the basic concept of what happens inside the proc:

**Step 1:**
Create a temp table that stores the entire result set. My preference is to store only two values in this temp table. An identity seed value called RowId and the primary key of the result data. (I'm one of those people that believes in non-sensical identity seed keys)

**Step 2:**
Insert all the PKey values from the select statement into the temp table

**Step 3:**
Determine the StartRowId and EndRowId based on the input page parameter.

**Step 4:**
Select from the temp table using an inner join to the datatable on the PKey. In the where clause limit the result so the RowId (of the temp table) is between StartRowId and EndRowId. Make sure to Order By the RowId.

Comment: Thanks for response. I have the same issue. Right now i am loading all the data from the database at once inside a table which act like a grid in my website. But there is lots of issue with this logic, when i redirect to any other page by <form Action="page name">, it reflects some error message. And when i provided a limit of 1000 data in my mysql query its working fine. So please suggest me any other way to show all data which in a huge quantity in database

Comment: I'm not going to write the stored procedure for you. It's time for you to learn how to build it from scratch. I have outlined the basic idea for how I have gone about doing this. The google link I provided earlier is also a good source.

Answer (score 0):

Set page size

```
recordset.PageSize = 100 ' number of records per page
```

Set the current page

```
recordset.AbsolutePage = nPage ' nPage being the page you want to jump to.
```

Other useful bits:

```
recordset.RecordCount ' number of records returned
recordset.PageCount ' number of pages based on PageSize and RecordCount
```

That's the basic info.  You'll still need to loop through the appropriate number of records, and check the page number as it is passed back to the page.

Comment: If the cursor does not support recordcount/pagecount properties, you can drop the recordset into an array (arrRS = recordset.getRows), and then write your own pagination.